# How to disable button in Angular reactive form after submit

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular reactive forms,
How can I disable a button and change the button label after clicked/submit?

Comment: This question shows that no effort was put into researching the problem. I have added an answer to help you learn a good approach to this sort of implementation, but you should try to add example code and "what I've tried already" detail in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Angular does not provide a "form submitted" property on forms. The best way would be to update a boolean (that you use in the template) when submitting the form and reset it when appropriate.

The following example uses reactive forms and fakes a POST with the form data.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm"
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  ... form stuff ...
  <button type="submit"
          [disabled]="isSubmitting">
    {{isSubmitting ? 'Submitting...' : 'Submit'}}
  </button>
</form>
```

```
onSubmit(): void {
  // catch if the form has errors
  if (this.myForm.invalid) return;

  // if no errors, continue with the submit
  this.isSubmitting = true;

  this.http
    .post('www.example.com', this.myForm.value)
    .subscribe(
      success => { this.isSubmitting = false },
      error => { ... handle the error ... }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a local variable and make it true when ever submit action happen. Also you can put variable name in button

```
<!-- html file->
<form [formGroup]='myForm' (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()'>
 ..........
 .........
<button type="submit" [disabled]="makeDisable"> {{btnName}} </button> 

// Ts file
btnName = 'submit'; // initial label
makeDisable = false;
onSubmit() {
   this.makeDisable = true;
   this.btnName = 'label changed'; // change the label
   // make API call If every thing is done put this code in async callbabck
   this.makeDisable = false;
   this.btnName = 'submit'; // restore the label
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is myForm.markAsPristine().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).